# Cross browser friendly, multi-page fullscreen, scroll to layout

Tags: jquery, css

I have a simple 2 page layout I'd like to create which I've run into some problems creating.

Both pages take the full width and height of the page. The second page exists, but is hidden off screen above (vertically) the first page. On clicking a button, the first page moves downward and the second page descends from above.

My first attempt involved 2 absolute positioned boxes. ie

```
#page1, #page2 { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#page2 { margin-top: -100%; }
```

Structurally, this works in Chrome. #page2 sits off the screen and page1 is visible. Unfortunately it doesn't play so nice for some other users.

On clicking my button with some simple jquery I animated the css like so:

```
$('#learnmore').click(function(){

    $('#page1').animate({'margin-top':'100%'},500);
    $('#page2').animate({'margin-top':'0'},500);
});
```

So basically, page 1 adds a margin of 100% and page2's margin is removed. This worked ok on my computer but other users reported issues. I figure it must be a structural problem with my layout.

It seems to me that different browsers don't like width: 100% and height: 100% and is creating some unexpected results. Is this true?

What would be a better way to achieve this so that the second page is hidden off screen, and scrolls down from above on click? The aim is to have page1 visible on load, without scrollbars on screen, and then once page2 is brought down, the user could then scroll back if desired.

EDIT: [**Here is a JSfiddle of a way I have gone about it using a different structure**](http://jsfiddle.net/MSAUS/3/) - do you see any problems with this on your browser? Can you improve on this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using 100% for margin-top, consider using $(window).height(). Will give you the same result and work for all browsers if you're sure that your initial screen has an height of 100%.

```
$('#learnmore').click(function(){

    $('#page1').animate({'margin-top':$(window).height()},500);
    $('#page2').animate({'margin-top':'0'},500);
});
```

You'll also need to set the width and height of your page1 to 100% too on document.ready()

```
$('#page1').css("height", $(window).height() + "px");
```

Do the same thing for #page2 in learnmore.click()